# Why are these lines of code causing keyboard lag and is there an alternative?

Tags: python, minecraft, lag

So I am learning python and I am trying to create a code that detects the time between pressing "space" and "a" for something in Minecraft. The problem is that this program lags my keyboard/causes delay in keyboard presses.

I've narrowed the issue down to this:

```
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed ('p'):
        strafe45()
```

If I replace this with something like this: It does not cause keyboard lag.

```
run = 1
while run == 1:
    strafe45()
```

I think it is because the first is constantly checking if I am typing 'p' or not, which is the cause of the lag, but how else can I write something like that? I cannot use while run == 1: because eventually it gives me an error since I am holding down 'a' and the variable 'start' does not have an assigned value any more.

Here is the full code if needed:

```
import keyboard
import time
import math

def strafe45():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed ('space'):
            print ("starting timer")
            start = time.perf_counter()
            time.sleep(0.05)
        if keyboard.is_pressed ('a'):
            end = time.perf_counter()
            print ("ending timer")
            tickTime = end - start
            tick = 0.05
            if tickTime > tick:
                print ("Did not make strafe. Too slow by " + str(tickTime - tick) + "\n" +
                        "Time passed (r): " + str(round(tickTime/tick, 2)) + "\n" +
                        "Time passed (a): " + str(tickTime/tick))
                break
            if tickTime < tick:
                print ("Did make strafe by " + str(tick - tickTime) + "\n" +
                       "Time passed (r): " + str(round(tickTime/tick, 2)) + "\n" +
                       "Time passed (a): " + str(tickTime/tick))
                break

run = 1
while run == 1:
    strafe45()
"""while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed ('p'):
        strafe45()"""
```

Comment: Rather than constantly checking each loop, add a hook and check only when a key is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed ('p'):
        strafe45()
```

When the `p` key is pressed, `strafe45` gets called, and some `sleep` calls happen as a result.

As long as the `p` key is *not* being pressed, there is a tight while loop that keeps checking for when the key gets pressed.

You should have a *single* `while` loop, *outside* the key-handling function, and ensure that a `time.sleep` call occurs every time through this loop - by putting it in the loop explicitly. If you call out to functions to handle the keys (a good idea as the code becomes more complicated), they should not have their own loop - they should just make the appropriate changes to the program state according to what was pressed.

For example:

```
begin = None
def begin_timing():
    global begin
    begin = time.perf_counter()

def end_timing():
    global begin
    if begin is not None: # otherwise, we weren't timing yet.
        end = time.perf_counter()
        print('elapsed time:', end - begin)
        begin = None # so that we can begin timing again.

while True:
    # There needs to be a delay each time through the loop,
    # but it needs to be considerably shorter than the time interval you're
    # trying to measure.
    time.sleep(0.01)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('b'): # begin
        begin_timing()
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('e'): # end
        end_timing()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than constantly checking each loop, add a hook and check only when a key is pressed. `keyboard.on_press(callback)` adds a listener to every keyboard and key that envokes the given callback. This should alleviate your latency issues. Check out the [Keyboard API Page](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.on_press) for full documentation

```
def check_key(x): #x should be an keyboard.KeyboardEvent
    print x.name, x.scan_code, x.time

    if x.name == "":
        something

    elif x.name == "":
        something else

keyboard.on_press(check_key)
```